# the winfo_height() returns incorrect value in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The print output of my code is,

> master.winfo_width:300,winfo_height:300
>
> frame.winfo_width:300,winfo_height:269

why is `frame.winfo_height()` 269 rather than 300?

Environment: Windows 10 Home 64 bit edition, python 3.7.4, tkinter verion 8.4

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MyFrame(tk.Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, master=None, width=10, height=10):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(master)
        self.bind_all('<Key>', self.keyevt)
        
    def keyevt(self, evt):
        print("self.winfo_width:%d,winfo_height:%d"%(self.winfo_width(),self.winfo_height()))


master = tk.Tk()
master.resizable(False, False)
master.geometry("300x300")
lander = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="./csdn.png")

frame = MyFrame(master, width=300, height=300)
master.update()
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
canvas.pack()
frame.pack()
frame.update()
imagelander = canvas.create_image(150, 150, image=lander)
canvas.pack()

print("master.winfo_width:%d,winfo_height:%d"%(master.winfo_width(),master.winfo_height()))
print("frame.winfo_width:%d,winfo_height:%d"%(frame.winfo_width(),frame.winfo_height()))
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: it has height 267 because `Canvas` has height 267. If you use `tk.Canvas(frame, height=300)` then `Canvas` and `Frame` will have height `300`. `Frame` changes size to size of its children objects.

Comment: or you would have to use `frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')` - but then you will have to check sizes after starting `mainloop()`

Comment: or you would have to use `frame.propagate(False)` to not use size of its children. But you have to use `super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height)` to change your frame size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Frame` changes size to fit to size of its childrens.

Because `Canvas` has default height `267` so automatically `Frame` has the same size. If you set

```
 canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, height=300)
```

then `Frame` will have height `300` too.

You can also turn off this and frame will not change its size

```
 frame.propagate(False)
```

---

If you will need to resize `Frame` when window change size then more useful can be

```
 frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
```

---

BTW: To set size in your own frame you have to send size to `super()

```
super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height) # , bg='red')
```

---

**Example code.**

I added background colors to see size of Canvas (green) and Frame (red).

I also removed image so everyone can easily copy code and run it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, width=10, height=10):
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height, bg='red')
        self.bind_all('<Key>', self.keyevt)

    def keyevt(self, evt):
        print("self.winfo_width:%d,winfo_height:%d"%(self.winfo_width(),self.winfo_height()))

def test(event=True):
    print("master: {}, {}".format(master.winfo_width(), master.winfo_height()))
    print("frame : {}, {}".format(frame.winfo_width(), frame.winfo_height()))
    print("canvas: {}, {}".format(canvas.winfo_width(), canvas.winfo_height()))

master = tk.Tk()
master.resizable(False, False)
master.geometry("300x300")

frame = MyFrame(master, width=300, height=300)
frame.propagate(False)
frame.pack()#expand=True, fill='both')

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bg='green')#, height=300)
canvas.pack()

print('before update')
test()

master.update()
print('after update')
test()

print('200 ms after starting mainloop')
master.after(200, test)

#print('when window change size')
#master.bind('<Configure>', test)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: furas, Thank you very much. By the way, where I can find the manual and api reference for tkinter? I cannot find the detailed api explanation for frame.pack from internet. I have checked https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.html

Comment: And neither there is information frame.propagate() in the link above

Comment: there is no good documentation. Popular documentation (but old and incomplete) is [documentation on effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm). `propagete` you can find in [Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) as `pack_propagate` and in [Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) as `grid_propagate`.